# Remove "No SIM Card in Phone" message

Tags: root-access, sim-card, htc-mytouch

I recently changed to a newer phone and currently using my old android phone as a sort of "ipod". However, it always shows the message that there is no sim card. I know this is just an annoyance but is there anyway to disable it? I am rooted running a custom sense 4 rom on ICS. Is there anything I could flash to remove this message? Or disable the cellular radio completely?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: I've tended to keep old Sim cards for just that purpose

Comment: There are Xposed modules to remove the 'no SIM' from the status bar, but I cannot find anything to remove the HTC one from the lock screen.

Answer (score 7):

You can remove the "No SIM" notification from the Galaxy S3 S4 and Note 3 by adding an entry to your build.prop. You need root to do this.

I recommend using [JRummy's Build Prop Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.apps.build.prop.editor). Once you've installed it, launch the app and click the bottom right icon (a `+` sign).

In the first box you can enter a description like so (this is optional):

```
# Remove "No SIM" from notification bar
```

In the second box, enter:

```
ro.config.donot_nosim= true
```

Then save and reboot.

If the "No SIM" popup still shows, or you get the "No SIM" notification icon, then look for an entry that reads:

```
ro.config.tima=1
```

and change that to:

```
ro.config.donot_nosim= true
```

If that still doesn't work, try removing `ro.config.tima=1` or set it to 0 instead of 1.

You can also add `sys.hiddenmenu.enable=1` to enable the hidden menu if it isn't already in your build.prop.

Comment: These Instructions worked for me on my Note 4.

Comment: Worked on my Note 2.

Comment: This did not work on my rooted Note 3.  Tried ro.config.tima=0, false, and removed entirely in every configuration with ro.config.donot_nosim=true and 1.  Bummer.  Wound up using an Xposed module.

Answer (score 6):

Turn on airplane mode, enable WiFi.  Problem gone.

Comment: Enabling Airplane mode (a) did not remove the SIM card persistent notification and (b) added a new persistent notification on my Note 3.  Unfortunately this answer is a bust.

Comment: You need to restart the phone after you put it into airplane mode. When it restarts the notification will never come up, probably because it never tries to connect to the mobile network.

Comment: Confirmed on unrooted S5 that psouza4 is correct. Now you'll have TWO annoying icons on your status bar, and, CodyF, restarting has no effect. So, this solution is worse than unhelpful.

Answer (score 4):

If you have root access:

- download the free "[Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff)" app from the Play store;
- open it;
- scroll all the way down till you find "system ui" and uncheck it;
- hit the little floppy disk icon at the top to save it.

This works for my Sprint Note 3 on page plus.

Comment: The app sounds nice, but won't that disable *all* system warnings, including potentially important ones?

Comment: @Tobias: it will, this should not be the solution

Answer (score 2):

Turn on Airplane Mode. It will turn off wifi unless you need wifi then I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Funny little quirk of most Android phones: You can turn on Airplane Mode and then turn on WiFi. So your cell radio and GPS stay off, but your WiFi will work. However, I don't see how this is going to help the Asker.

Comment: @Al - This is not just a quirk of Android. iPads work similar - Airplane mode still allows you to independently turn Wifi on.

Comment: This is the proper solution.

Comment: As has been pointed out in a duplicate answer to this question, for at least some phones (perhaps all?), this will not help. Not only does Airplane NOT remove the no-sim-card icon & notification, but it also triggers its own airplane mode icon. This answer proved to be unhelpful.